# How do I add try/except for the case where sex is misspelled?

Tags: python, python-2.7, error-handling

I need to add a try/except for the case where the user misspells the words "Male" or "Female."

Below is how I have it in my code right now but my assignment calls for me to incorporate try/except for the misspelling of "Male" or "Female."  The following try/except code I used helped to solve the issue of the user inputting a word for age but not the misspelling of their sex.

Any help is appreciated.

```
fem_names = []
fem_ages = []
male_names = []
male_ages = []


while True:
  try:                                               
    name = raw_input('Enter name:')                             
    age = raw_input('Enter age:')                               
    sex = raw_input('Enter female or male:')                    

    if (sex == 'female'):                                       
        fem_names.append(name)                                  
        fem_ages.append(float(age))                             

    else:                                                       
        male_names.append(name)                                 
        male_ages.append(float(age))                            
    reply = raw_input('Type yes to continue or no to stop:')    
    if (reply == "no"):                                         
        break                                                   
  except Exception:
    print('Please enter correct information')

tot_fem = len(fem_names)                                                                        
tot_fem_ages = sum(fem_ages)                                    
if(tot_fem == 0):                                                
  avg_fem_age = 0.0                                             

else:                                                           
  avg_fem_age = tot_fem_ages/tot_fem       




tot_male = len(male_names)                                      
tot_male_ages = sum(male_ages)                                  
if(tot_male == 0):                                              
  avg_male_age = 0.0                                            

else:                                                           
  avg_male_age = tot_male_ages/tot_male                                          


print "There are", tot_fem , "total females with an average age of" , avg_fem_age, "years."             
print "There are", tot_male , "total males with an average age of" , avg_male_age, "years."
```

Comment: You should start by reading [the Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html).

Comment: Share your syntax error.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `except`, not `Except`?

Comment: `except` statements (note case) are valid only as part of a `try` statement. Also, they catch errors; what error are you trying to catch? Just entering something other than "male" or "female" is not an error.

Comment: You don't mean *"add an exception"*, you mean *"add error-handling for the case when `sex` is invalid"*. You would do that with normal control flow like `if-then-else, break, continue`, not by raising exceptions.

Comment: @kindall Thx! That makes sense but the assignment calls for try/except in case of the misspelling or sex (which is not an error like you said)... need to speak to my instructor

Answer (score 0):

you can check first the 'sex' using 'if'

```
sex = raw_input('Enter female or male:')                    
if sex in ['male', 'female']:
    if (sex == 'female'):                                       
        fem_names.append(name)                                  
        fem_ages.append(float(age))                             

    else:                                                       
        male_names.append(name)                                 
        male_ages.append(float(age)) 
else:
       # raise error here
       print "invalid sex"
```